# looping to pull the first 2 substrings of a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, substring

I am attempting to pull a substring form a column, in the following way:

```
target_column: 

PE123
DD123-HP123
HP123
373627HP23
```

I would like to pull the first two strings/alphabets of every record, except in cases where there is no alphabet in the first two strings. In this case, pull any alphabet that you find in the rest of the string. So in the case of 373627HP23, it will pull HP.

But the problem is with something like DD123-HP123. My loop is pulling the HP instead of the DD.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    target_value = row['target_column']
    predefined_code = [HP]           
     for code in re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", target_value):
         if (len(code)!=1) and not (code in predefined_code):
             possible_code = code
```

What is wrong with my code here?

What is the best code to write a loop so that in the case of something like DD123-HP123, it will pull the DD and not the HP?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: the following are the expected outputsPE
DD
HP
HP

Comment: OK, added solution, please check if working with real data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for return first matched pattern:

```
df['new'] = df['target_column'].str.extract("([a-zA-Z]+)")
print (df)
  target_column new
0         PE123  PE
1   DD123-HP123  DD
2         HP123  HP
3    373627HP23  HP
```